# If inside while loop

Tags: python

```
again = True

while(again == True):

    yn = input("Do you want to do it again? (y or n)").lower()

    if(yn == 'y' or 'yes'):
        again == True
    elif(yn == 'n' or 'no):
        again == False
```

How do I make this code work? When I run it, it will always come out to be true.. =/

Comment: Note that on the second to last line, you are missing a quote.

`elif(yn == 'n' or 'no'):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning:

`while(again == True):`

1. You don't need the parentheses here
2. You don't need the `== True` bit. `again` is suffice as it will have a boolean value of True.

`if(yn == 'y' or 'yes'):`

1. Once again, parenthesis aren't needed.
2. That line of code is translated as `if (yn == 'y') or ('yes'):`. This will always be true as `'yes'` is considered `True` (not an empty string)
3. In python, you need to do `if yn == 'y' or yn == 'yes':`
4. Or you can do `if yn in ('y', 'yes')`

`again == True`

1. `==` is for comparisons. `=` is for assignments
2. This occurs in your `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

In the final 4 lines of your program you aren't assigning `again` to have the value true, you are checking if `again` equals `True`/`False`.

`==` is completely different from `=`.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work:

```
if (yn == 'y' or 'yes'):
    # ...
elif(yn == 'n' or 'no):
```

The correct way is:

```
if yn in ('y' or 'yes'):
    # ...
elif yn in ('n' or 'no):
```

Also, inside the conditions the assignments are wrong, use a single `=`. They should look like this:

```
again = True
# ...
again = False
```

Comment: Okay this works now, but when I enter something else other than no it will repeat itself. How do I make it only respond to yes?

Comment: @user2840982 then add another condition in an `else:` to take this case in consideration, for instance, ask the user to enter a correct input. Or do as @JasonSundram suggests, and replace the whole `elif` line with an `else:`

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking the equality operator `==` with the assignment operator `=`.  Also the statement `yn == 'y' or 'yes'` is buggy, since the right hand side is a non-empty string, which evaluates to `True` in a boolean context.

Declaring a variable simply to handle loop termination is not pythonic.  I would rewrite your code entirely to be:

```
while True:
    yn = input("Do you want to do it again? (y or n)").lower()
    if yn in ('n','no'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

if(yn == 'y' or 'yes'):
   # ----

The value of above statement is always true independent of valu of “yn” because right side of “or” is always true in your case. so it will never execute else part. So to avoid this, You have to compare value of “yn” with each possibility.
one of the simple way is that

```
if(yn == 'y' or yn == 'yes'):
    again == True
elif(yn == 'n' or yn == 'no):
    again == False
```

Answer (score -1):

your if else statment should be

if xxx:
  again = True
elif yyy:
  again = False

Note difference between = and ==.